# WKWebview Scroll becomes slow and laggy when Scrollview delegate methods are implemented

Tags: html, ios, swift, scrollview, wkwebview

I am loading simple HTML In WKWebview but as soon as I implement delegate methods

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        scrollByDragging = true
      
       print("dragged")
    }
    
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if  scrollByDragging {
         webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)

           print("didScroll",scrollView.contentOffset)
       }
    }
```

The scroll becomes really slow on dragging ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This was basically because of line of code

> webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset,
> animated: true)

As soon as it was removed the wkwebview scroll  got its power back .